# Limsup of random variables vs limsup of events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, limsup-and-liminf, borel-cantelli-lemmas

In [2.7](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejames/Lectures/pm7.pdf) of this notes, it is shown that, using Borel-Cantelli lemma, if $E_n = \left\{\frac{X_n}{\log n} \geq 1\right\}$ then $\mathbb{P}(\limsup \ E_n) = 1$ but why does author conclude that if $Y = \limsup \frac{X_n}{\log n}$, then $\mathbb{P}(Y \geq 1) = 1$ ?

My question is Borel-cantelli lemma says events $\limsup$ of some events is 0 or 1, but in most books and online notes, an event in terms of random variable $\limsup X_n$ concluded to have probability 0 or 1. Can someone clarify the confusion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $a_n \geq 1$ for infinitely many values of $n$ then $\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} a_n \geq 1$. Hence the event $(\frac {X_n} {\log n} \geq 1 \,\, \text {i.o.} )$ is contained in the event  $(\lim \sup_{n \to \infty} \frac {X_n} {\log n} \geq 1)$.

Comment: What is generally true is $(\lim \sup Y_n \geq c)$ is contains $\lim \sup$ of the events $(Y_n \geq c)$. But the reverse inclusion fails in general.  Ex: $Y_n=1-\frac 1 n, c=0$. @Tiramisu

Comment: Got it @KaviRamaMurthy. Thank you.

Comment: you mean $c=1$ in your counterexample, right? (not $c=0$)